# Modulo in a conditional expression

Tags: c++, modulo, modulus

I'm very new to programming and am starting out with Bjourne's book: Programming principles and practice c++ 2nd edition. Exercise 8 chapter 3 he asks for:

> "Write a program to test an integer value to determine if it is odd or even...Hint: See the remainder (modulo)operator in §3.4."

I can do that with something like:

```
int main() {
int n;
cout << "Enter an integer: ";
cin >> n;
if ( n%2 == 0) {
    cout << n << " is even.";
}
else {
    cout << n << " is odd.";

}
return 0;
}
```

But he gives in his website his own solution:

```
int main()
{
int val = 0;
cout << "Please enter an integer: ";
cin >> val;;
if (!cin) error("something went bad with the read");
string res = "even";
if (val%2) res = "odd"; 

cout << "The value " << val << " is an " << res << " number\n";

keep_window_open(); 
}
catch (runtime_error e) {   
cout << e.what() << '\n';
keep_window_open("~");  
}

/*
Note the technique of picking a default value for the result ("even") and changing it only 
if needed.
The alternative would be to use a conditional expression and write
    string res = (val%2) ? "even" : "odd";
```

What is

```
string res = "even";
if (val%2) res = "odd";
```

and

```
string res = (val%2) ? "even" : "odd";
```

actually doing? I haven't seen him explaining those before in the book. Also, the last code, It gives me "odd" result when I type an even value and gives an "even " result when I type and odd one. what is going on? Sorry for the long post, hope I could explain what I need...

Comment: I can understand you haven't seen ternary operator before, but are you wondering what `if` does?

Comment: Maybe I can't grasp how (val%2) works as a condition in an If statement...

Comment: Well, you can now. You've got answers.

Comment: `if(x)` means `if( (x) != 0 )`, where `x` is any expression

Comment: Awesome, thanks man!

Answer (score 3):

The ? : is the [ternary operator](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjjyJ_EmMPJAhWEbj4KHWl_D2EQFggfMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FTernary_operation&usg=AFQjCNFypNXuudzQC3Pdx7-uE-lW92Ve7w&sig2=YRl5O99qW6jsWZ7Ttbccsg).

```
if (val%2) res = "odd";
```

is just a rather terse version of

```
if (val%2) {
  res = "odd";
}
```

And note that `if(...)` actually *doesn't* care whether the value is "true" or "false." It just checks for zero or nonzero. So it's equivalent to

```
if( val%2 != 0)
```

The second command line : `string res = (val%2) ? "even" : "odd";` similary is a short way for writing:

```
string res;
if(val%2 != 0){
    res = "even";
}
else{
    res = "odd";
}
```

The syntax for those kind of commands is `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`

Comment: `condition ? value_if_true : value_if_false`  but if **true** in this case is _!=0_ or simply the value of _1_, shouldn't the value of **res** be _"odd" _instead of _"even"_??

Answer (score 1):

Adding to the previous answers, you have to note the boolean (or "true" values) are 0s and 1s, (0 being false and 1 being true in boolean algebra)

So, when

```
string res = (val % 2) ? "even" : "odd";
```

Note that when you give and odd value it will always return number 1 which is "true", and viceversa for even numbers.

You would have to turn those around for the program to work.

Comment: By turning around u mean : `string res = (val % 2) ? "odd" : "even";`?

Comment: Yep, I mean, it's obvious that if you turn it around, by seeing your problem it will work. But keep in mind that that val % 2, being val = any odd number, will result in "1" which equals to "true", so the true statement will execute.

Comment: Thank God! I'm trying to get an answer to this piece of code since yesterday, even asked here in the comments but to no avail. I mean, I figured it out that just swapping these two values would make the program work, but since the book had that way and I'm a noob, I was skeptical about "fixing" it... too bad I can't +rep you right now. TY again.

Comment: Don't worry! I'm just helping. :) People seem to forget to analyze what's really happening behind the curtains sometimes.

Good luck and happy programming!

Answer (score 0):

He just instead of writing multiple brackets, does not use them at all

```
string res = "even"; //default value 
if (val%2) res = "odd"; //in case it is odd, value changes 

//output or threat in some way value.
```

instead

```
string res = (val%2) ? "even" : "odd";
```

Simply a short way of writing the same `if/else` you wrote before.

Comment: `string res = (val%2) ? "even" : "odd";`  but this gives me "even" for odd numbers and "odd" for even numbers...